# get all currencies available for website/store in magento

Tags: php, api, magento

thanks for reading, I'm new to magento. I'm working on api application,so if I have the website id how can I get all available currencies for this website and same thing if I have store id
any idea will be appreciated

Comment: What's said in documentation?

Comment: Post some code you already tried

Comment: documentation says that variables are website_id for website currencies and store_id for store currencies

Comment: I've tried this for store but it returns only the default currency: Mage::app()->getStore(store_id)->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

Comment: I came across a command and it returned all allowed currencies in array but without any hint to website id or store id: Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getConfigAllowCurrencies();

Answer (score 4):

try this one:

```
$CurrencyCode = Mage::getModel('core/config_data')
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('path','currency/options/allow')
->addFieldToFilter('scope_id',<you store id>)
->getData();
$currencies_array = explode(',',$CurrencyCode[0]['value']);
if($currencies_array[0] == '')
{
    $currencies_array[]= Mage::app()->getStore($site_id)->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($currencies_array);echo "</pre>";
```

where  should be replaced by store id.

Remember, if you have not set value for specific store, you need to pass 0 (default store scope id).

Comment: Wow .. you're my hero I've been trying for 6 hours today
this is working but instead of store id, it takes website id,so it returns all currencies for the given website id, I'll try to make it work for store id too ... thanks a lot my friend :-)

Comment: it's not allowed to me to vote up your answer .. so sory

Comment: Thanks rramiii for editing my answer.. now it is more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Try following, haven't tested it.

```
    $currencies = array();
    $codes = Mage::app()->getStore()->getAvailableCurrencyCodes(true);
    if (is_array($codes) && count($codes) > 1) {
        $rates = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates(
                Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrency(),
                $codes
        );

        foreach ($codes as $code) {
            if (isset($rates[$code])) {
                $currencies[$code] = Mage::app()->getLocale()
                ->getTranslation($code, 'nametocurrency');
            }
        }
    }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($currencies);
```

Comment: thank you,Mage::app()->getStore()->getAvailableCurrencyCodes(true) returns the default currency, so by replacing it with Mage::app()->getStore()->getAvailableCurrencyCodes(true) will return all available currencies in the system with country name, but still can't get currencies for specified website OR store(I have the id for the wanted website and store)

Comment: if we open system->configuration->currency setup, this configuration for currencies differ by the selected website or store, so I think there is some way to get currencies by website or store, the question is howwwww :((((((

Comment: I used code to get magento currency rates ($rates variable) from here, very useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to get allowed currencies:

```
$CurrencyCode = Mage::getStoreConfig('currency/options/allow');
```

Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: thank you for help but this command returned the default currency only
I came across a command and it returned all allowed currencies in array but without any hint to website id or store id: Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getConfigAllowCurrencies();

Comment: If you are using my code from frontend, then it will detect store (by default) and show you current store's currencies.

I have tested it in multi website and multi store set up also.

Comment: but the requested is any website id or any store id passed to my api function, so my function has to take the id and return the currencies associated with the requested website or store :-(

Comment: try this one:

$CurrencyCode = Mage::getModel('core/config_data')
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('path','currency/options/allow')
->addFieldToFilter('scope_id',<you store id>)
->getData();

echo "<pre>";print_r($CurrencyCode[0]['value']);echo "</pre>";

where <you store id> should be replaced by store id.

Remember, if you have not set value for specific store, you need to pass 0 (default store scope id).

Answer (score 0):

I needed some currencies for a drop down on a custom grid. To get the list of currencies used in all stores and render a drop down, this worked for me in Grid.php

```
    $stores = Mage::app()->getStores();
    foreach($stores as $store) {
        $currency = Mage::getStoreConfig('currency/options/allow', $store);
        $currencies[$currency] = $currency;
    }
    $currencies = array_unique($currencies);
```

For the grid column:

```
    $this->addColumn('currency', array(
                     'header' => Mage::helper('erp')->__('Currency'),
                     'align' => 'left',
                     'width' => '100px',
                     'index' => 'currency',
                     'type'  => 'options',
                     'options' => $currencies,
                     ));
```

I did not need the option labels of the currency names in long form, just the three letter codes.